# How to get a button state to save after signing out and sign back in?

Tags: swift, button, firebase-realtime-database

I have a save button that when tapped, will save the text in a label (quoteLabel) to a user account in Firebase. The button will then hide and the unsave button will no longer be hidden so that the user can unsave if desired. Both of these buttons are able to post and delete data as desired, however, if I sign-out of the app and sign back in, the buttons are reset to their original status. How do I get the button to stay in the last state it was set to?  I can't seem to get this to work. Please let me know if more information is needed, I'm still new to all this.

Edit: Updated with suggestions from below. I still can't seem to get this to work properly. When I tap just one button, they all end up being saved as tapped when I sign back in. I added how I assigned a key as well.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class QuotesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var quoteLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var save: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var unsave: UIButton!
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: uuid)

save.isHidden = true
unsave.isHidden = false

var ref: DatabaseReference?
ref = Database.database().reference()

if quoteLabel.text == "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown"{

guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quote").child("Quote1").setValue(quoteLabel.text!)
    
}

}

@IBAction func UnsaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: uuid)


save.isHidden = false
unsave.isHidden = true

var ref: DatabaseReference?
ref = Database.database().reference()

if quoteLabel.text == "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown"{
ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quote").child("Quote1").removeValue()

}


}

func setup(with quote: Quotes){
let saveButtonShowing = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: uuid)
if(saveButtonShowing){ // Retrieves the state variable from the hard drive and sets the button visibility accordingly
    save.isHidden = true
    unsave.isHidden = false
} else {
    save.isHidden = false
    unsave.isHidden = true
}

quoteLabel.text = quote.quote


}
}
```

This is how I tried to add a key to each quote:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


let uuid = UUID().uuidString


struct Quotes {
let quote: String
let identifier: String

}

let quotes: [Quotes] = [
Quotes(quote: "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown", identifier:  uuid),
                        Quotes(quote:    "Everytime you spend money, you're casting a vote for the type of world you want - Anna Lappe",identifier: uuid),
                        Quotes(quote: "Buy less, choose well, make it last - Vivienne Westwood", identifier: uuid),
                        Quotes(quote: "The future depends on what we do in the present - Mahatma Gandhi", identifier: uuid),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .isHidden property of the UIButton's is a state variable, meaning it is saved in RAM. This means that once you exit the application and reopen it, your app will startup again with the default state variable settings.
If you wish to *persist* the state of these variables, you'll need to save the button states to the phone's hard drive. UserDefaults makes this easy.

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "saveButtonHidden") // Saves the state to the hard drive

    save.isHidden = true
    unsave.isHidden = false

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    if quoteLabel.text == "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown"{
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quote").chi.ld("Quote1").setValue(quoteLabel.text!)
    }

}


@IBAction func UnsaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "saveButtonHidden") // Saves the state to the hard drive

    save.isHidden = false
    unsave.isHidden = true

    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    if quoteLabel.text == "The best time to plant a tree was 20 years ago - The next best time is today - Unknown"{
        ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quote").child("Quote1").removeValue()
    }

    if quoteLabel.text as! NSObject == ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quote").child("Quote1") {
        save.isHidden = true
        unsave.isHidden = false
    }
}


func setup(with quote: Quotes){
    let saveButtonShowing = UserDefault.standard.bool(forKey: "saveButtonHidden")
    if(saveButtonHidden){ // Retrieves the state variable from the hard drive and sets the button visibility accordingly
        save.isHidden = true
        unsave.isHidden = false
    } else {
        save.isHidden = false
        unsave.isHidden = true
    }
    
    quoteLabel.text = quote.quote
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had to make a couple of minor edits to get it functional. In func setup UserDefault was changed to UserDefaults and saveButtonHidden to saveButtonShowing. However, since its a collection view it makes these changes across all buttons. How do I get the above to apply to the collection view as well?

Comment: Just make a unique user defaults key for each label. This may look something like UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "saveButtonShowing1432") for one button, and UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "saveButtonShowing9853") for another button. How you assign the keys is up to you, just make sure that the keys will be the same across every app open, this may mean saving an associated key with each quote in the realtime database.

Comment: I updated the code above with your suggestion. I assume I did something wrong since it's still behaving the same way. Would greatly appreciate any further advice.

Comment: Weird. I’m not seeing your implemented UserDefaults related code in your functions above. Could you edit your question with that code included so I can look at that?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the code. I just used the suggestion you gave, but I didn't do something correctly. Did I add the keys correctly for each label at least?

Comment: Okay yeah, so you've correctly assigned each Quote a label, however, in your code, your user defaults keys are unconditionally equal to "QuoteButton1". This means that even if your QuotesCollectionViewCell object is supposed to display the second quote, it will still derive it's button state from the key "QuoteButton1". This means that your UserDefaults key MUST be a variable- a variable which depends on the specific quote which the QuotesCollectionViewCell represents. In essence, when you are displaying quote number five, the key should be "QuoteButton5" (Not "QuoteButton1").

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you for this. I'll see if I can work this out. Also, if I added more quotes to this list, lets say 50 or 100, would I no longer want to use user defaults? Would I want to just use Firebase only instead?

Comment: Well the question isn't about how many quotes you have. You can store tons of information in user defaults for basically no storage cost. The issue arises when you consider multiple devices. If you suspect you'll ever want to allow the user to sign in and view quotes from multiple devices at once, pure firebase will certainly be the way to go. This is because the UserDefaults storage is saved locally, thus it won't transfer across devices.

Comment: Also, I would advise that you use some form of identification other than "Quote1", "Quote2", etc. This is because I suspect you'll want users to be able to delete quotes and add new ones. That would create some interesting bugs where if you delete the second quote ("Quote2"), and then create a new second quote, that new quote would be under the id "Quote2", meaning UserDefaults will already think that the saveButton should be hidden. Rather than using these identifiers, I would look into assigning each quote an id via UUID. You can generate a UUID in swift with UUID().uuidString.

Comment: ok, I updated with UUID, however I'm still getting the same behavior. Its as if uuid is being recognized as a single value rather than generating a unique ID. Is there something that I missed to get the unique ID?

Comment: Every time you call UUID(), a new uuid will be generated. In your code, you're only calling UUID() once (you're setting it to a constant at the top of the file), meaning that that uuid will be used for every quote. In order to generate a new uuid, you'll have to call UUID() again. Once for each quote. However, remember that you can only retrieve information from user defaults if you're accessing it through the same key which you set it to, meaning that you should call UUID() ONCE for each time you create a quote, and retrieve that specified uuid from firebase all other subsequent times.

Comment: Again, you may also consider removing UserDefaults from the equation altogether, and setting the button state based on something purely stored in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the info on local device.
the best way is to store the info on firebase according to the user info.
I think it's no problem to show the code here.

Comment: Is storing locally a problem if I want users to be able to sign in and out on different devices?

Comment: yes, for other devices, it's not good way to store it on local device.
that's why I said the best way is to store it on firebase database.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, sorry. Any recommendations on how to go about that? I can't seem to figure out how to determine if a user has saved a particular quote or not.

Comment: You can make any column on user field of firebase.
You can save the button status on the field, and then you will check the field when user login.